# Google App Engine Security Constraint is not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm using the following security constraint in the deployment descriptor of my GWT app, which is deployed on Google App Engine (GAE) for Java:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>ds/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

My app is using Google Accounts for authentication.

It works perfectly fine in the hosted mode (Eclipse), but when I deploy the app to GAE, the constraint doesn't work. For example, in the hosted mode, when I try to access a resource in the ds folder, it redirects me to the login page. After login, it gives access to admin users only. But in the deployed app, anyone can access the resource without any authentication / authorization.

I haven't had a chance to test this on the "default" version of the app (http://myappid.appspot.com), but it surely doesn't work on other versions (like http://5.myappid.appspot.com).

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried adding below, but it is not working for me...<!-- Require user login for all URL's -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint> If I dont have the Security Constraint, then it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have thought you needed `/ds/*` .  Your example doesn't have a preceding slash.

Comment: @planetjones - Thanks, but it still doesn't work. I think I had the forward slash there earlier, but it didn't work. Then I removed it and that didn't work either. Now I tried it again with `/ds/*` and it still doesn't work. Actually both work in the hosted mode. Any other ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, take a look at google examples: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication
They always use full path patterns.

Comment: @DFB, dumb questions, but did you logout of your Google account before acessing the page? Have you tried to redeploy, logout and clean your cache before visiting the page?

Comment: @ Anthony - I think the problem was the cache and my understanding of how browser 'stealth' modes work. I thought if I open up a fresh 'stealth' mode window in a browser such as Chrome, it would not read anything from the cache. But apparently, it doesn't work that way. It still reads the file from the cache. However, it doesn't get the login information from the cookie. So, while I'm not logged, I could still see the file. It works fine and I feel dumb now :) Thanks to both of you for help.

Comment: Just reflecting back on it, I'm not sure why it always worked in the hosted mode. Probably it doesn't read the files from the cache in the hosted mode, and that misled me into thinking that something was wrong with GAE. Well anyway ...

Comment: @DFB, don't feel bad. Not a week goes by without me complaining about something and finding out it was a matter of cleaning the cache / session / updating a library / redeploying the App :D.

Comment: And about the hosted mode. Maybe it has something to do with redeploys and restarting the jetty based sandbox. I have no idea about how the sandbox emulates authentication concerns, but I'm pretty sure the session (and probably the cookies) gets invalidated somehow.