# Accessing a Google Account authenticated Web Service hosted on App Engine without browser login

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, authentication

I have various RESTful Web Servicesin App Engine, which are secured Google Account authentication:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Authentication required</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Upon hitting these Web Services via a browser client, I'm redirected to the Google Accounts login screen where I authenticate myself first before proceeding with the REST call.

However I now need to run these web service via a command line scripts as part of automated IC run. Therefore I do not want to be prompted for a browser login every time. Preferably I would like to put the Google username and password in a encrypted file on the IC server and let it call the Web Services without any human intervention. As far as I can see there are several options:

- manually logging in via the browser and then saving the access token to be used in the command line script. However when the token expire I would have issues.
- obtain a access token via Service Account p12 authentication. This seems to only work for accessing Google APIs such as BigQuery and Cloud Storage, not your own code.
- wrap my Web Service within a Remote API which I have yet to experiment with.

Based on my current understanding, it seems there is no way for a Google Account authenticated custom written Web Service to be accessed by a non-human user. Is this correct?

Comment: this question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872974/google-app-engine-security-constraint-is-not-working However I'm open to using Service Accounts instead of just username and password

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in interacting with RESTful web-services programmatically (*without human intervention*), we are essentially talking about [securing a REST API](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19930/how-do-i-secure-my-rest-api).

There is a plethora of resources on this matter throughout the internet but the gist of it is:

**you should use SSL and sessions or OAuth to secure your endpoints.**

Depending on how far you are in the current project, you could consider making use of [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/), there you'll have the option to use OAuth2 (and have DDoS protection), as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work in the end by:

1. Switching off the web.xml security-constraint so that the API doesn't redirect to Google Login.
2. Modifying my API to take in a Oauth2 token in the Authorization header instead.
3. Validating the token based on the code sample here: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-java

I didn't go with Cloud Endpoints, but Jersey + Dropwizard components instead. Dropwizard has built in [Oauth2Provider](http://dropwizard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/auth.html#oauth2) which I simply implemented a Authenticator class and it works.